# Python regex to find sequences matching: word + whitespace + word

Tags: python, regex

I am new to using regular expressions and have been trying to figure out a way of selecting an element of a list which contains two words seperated by whitespace.

I have the following dummy list:
['word <= 0.02', 'word_one <= 0.04', 'word two <= 0.01']

I would like only element 3 matched ('word two <= 0.01')

I have tried using:  \b\w+(?=\s)\b which I cut bits and pieces out of other related questions from stack overflow to find. I know this doesn't work, as there is whitespace after the second word (before <=) however I am just stuck trying to figure out how to fix it.

Here is an example of my code:

```
example_list = ['word <= 0.02', 'word_one <= 0.04', 'word two <= 0.01']

new_list = []

regex = '\b\w+(?=\s)\b'

for i in example_list:
    if re.match(regex, i):
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a string starting with 1+ word chars, then 1+ whitespaces and then again a word char, you may use

```
import re
example_list = ['word <= 0.02', 'word_one <= 0.04', 'word two <= 0.01']
new_list = []
regex = r'\w+\s+\w+\b'
for i in example_list:
    if re.match(regex, i):
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
# => ['word two <= 0.01']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/qAtF74).

Note `re.match` already anchors the match at the start of string, hence no `^` in the above regex. Also, as you used a regular string literal, `\b` in your pattern are backspace chars, not word boundary patterns.

If you need to match a string that has word char + whitespace(s) + word char anywhere in the string, replace `re.match` with `re.search` and you may even use `r'\w\s+\w'`. Or, if you really need to check word boundaries, `r'\b\w+\s+\w+\b'`.